# PayPal IPN signals to register user

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, django-registration, django-paypal

I am trying to get two third party apps to talk to each other: Django-paypal and django-registration. After a successful payment, PayPal sends an IPN signal to a supplied url. I want this signal to authenticate a user registered with django-registration.

After successful payment, it appears that the IPN isn't being sent by paypal sandbox, but I'm not sure it just ins't something wrong with the way I have my signal code set up.

The signals.py is imported in the **init**.py with

```
import signals
```

And I'm using ngrok to allow paypal sandbox to access my localhost.

views.py:

```
def payment(request):

    """
    This is the view for the page a new user is redirected
    to after registering (not activating) a new account.
    """

    paypal_dict = {
        "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "a3": "7.99",
        "p3": "1",
        "t3": "M",
        "src": "1",
        "sra": "1",
        "no_note": "1",
        "item_name": "My Item",
        "notify_url": "http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/account_activated/",
        "return_url": "http://localhost:8000/",
        "cancel_return": "http//www.example.com/cancel-location/",


    }

    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render_to_response("registration/registration_complete.html", context)
```

signlas.py:

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received, payment_was_flagged

from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from registration.views import ActivationView

def payment_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_object = sender
    if ipn_object.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        print "payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED"

        """
        Here use django-registration to authenticate
        the User
        """

        activate_user(activation_key)

        activation_key = ACTIVATED

        #ActivationView.activate()

    else:
        print str(ipn_object.payment_status)
        print "error"

valid_ipn_received.connect(payment_signal)  
payment_was_flagged.connect(payment_signal)

print "SIGNALS MODULE IMPORTED"
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/account_activated/$', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```

Comment: You may be interested in an article I wrote about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  If you follow those steps I'm sure you'll find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using a test port (like `8000`) rather than a standard port `80`.

When I switched to port `80`, I was able to receive the IPN notification, trigger a signal, and handle the signal appropriately.

This question led me down that path: [How do I allow django-merchant to receive paypal IPN conformations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392384/how-do-i-allow-django-merchant-to-receive-paypal-ipn-conformations)

Comment: I was able to do this, and using ngrok and IPN tester, I am able to send the IPN and get a 200 code from ngrok, but on my django development server console I see code '200 502'

Comment: I believe that means your django development server is acknowledging receipt of the HTTP packet [see code 200 OK](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Have you registered receivers for the IPN signals from django-paypal in the app.ready() method? If not, then IPN would notify django, but your application will do nothing with the data.